# Planner tasks endpoint always returns a 403?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to get tasks assigned to a specific user from the Graph API, so based off of the sample query in the graph explorer i'm using this endpoint

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-email>/planner/tasks`

Which works fine for whatever user I'm signed in as, but attempting to get tasks for a user I'm not signed in as will always return with a 403 and say I don't have the required permissions. Group.ReadWrite.All is granted by admin, and according to the graph docs, that should be fine, but no luck.

I've also just created a new demo tenant and one by one granted permissions in the graph explorer with admin and still no luck! So i'm doubting the issue really is permissions. And for the record I've tried v1.0 and beta endpoints, and I've attempted this in a SPFx Web Part, and it doesn't work in practice either.

Not sure that it will help, but this is what is being returned each time:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b02e3529-a4ae-4825-b4e6-7fc9b1fa228e",
            "date": "2019-03-27T12:28:41"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone else ran into this issue or know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading tasks for other people is not allowed. We are investigating app-only request support, which should enable this scenario.